# How to behave in a museum?

Tags: culture, museums, cultural-awareness

While travelling, specially in cities, it is common to visit museums. Since tourists come from a lot of countries, you encounter other ways of approaching the museum and the experience.

However, it is also common in this places to be crowded and there is a "competition" for the best space or the best angle while taking pictures.

What kind of courtesy can you expect when visiting a museum? Do you have to adopt your own country courtesy to the one from the country you are visiting? And what about visiting country A being you from country B and other people from country C?

For example: if you are used to silent museums, are you entitled to ask people to speak low or you should just give up if the museum workers do not do it?

Yet another example: if you see people touring in the rooms on a different direction as the flow, are you entitled to ask the people to be careful? Also if kids are crying very loud and parents do not care, etc.

So the general question here is: what kind of politeness is supposed to cover a "museum experience"?

Comment: I'd say things like this should always be lead by the customs of the country you're in, and/or the community within that country who run this particular museum.

Comment: And, apparently, the particular rules of the museum at the time you visit.  http://www.smh.com.au/good-weekend/clothes-off-for-a-naked-art-tour-at-the-national-gallery-of-australia-20150424-1miji6.html

Comment: Time honoured advice: "When in Rome, do as the Romans do". BUT erring on the sensible side when in doubt is mostly wise.| Id people are failing to observe posted rules AND it is affecting you adversely you may consider complaining BUT I'd expect both individuals and organisations to usually tend to ignore you. If a museum wants to enforce its rules it will. If its not doing so it will generally are if you do not approve. [When I stand on the guardrail in the dark hidden corner of the Australian, Canberra War memorial museum to photograph the Me262 security sends a polite understanding  ...

Comment: attendant to suggest that I desist. If anyone else commented they would have not been adding to my knowledge. (But I'd not do that with others there). (They obviously had a video camera somewhere). | Related (maybe): In Honk-kong floor arrows reflect British keep to the left. People walk Chinese- keep-to-the-right. Suggesting they follow the arrows would be far more amusing than useful. | I have politely suggested that noisy profane people leave a mosque and "party" outside when the 'owners' ignored them (which is VERY unusual). They complied. |

Comment: Too broad, too opinion based, not specific enough.

Comment: As someone who often goes "against the flow" (partially I think because I'm left-handed), I would be quite offended if anyone but a museum guard/employee asked me to change direction. If it was very crowded or a special exhibit, then I'd mind it more excusable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When visiting another country and their museums, you should/must follow the local customs and regulations.

One should always be respectful of the others; If you feel someone is not respectful, then notify the museum staff; they will handle the situation themselves; do NOT put yourself in a position of confrontation.

IMO, some of the rules that should be applied to museums (*):

- No selfie sticks.
- No selfie if in a crowded place.
- No touching the art pieces.
- No flash in museums; and if you do not know how to disable the flash, do NOT take a picture.
- Talking should be kept to a minimum and at a low level.
- No food/drinks.

(*) Art museum should be considered more stringent in the application of the rules while science museum will probably be less (especially in noise level).